# Android ViewPager not filling screen on Galaxy Nexus only

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I'm trying to create a ViewPager that takes up the entire screen.  Inside each fragment of the ViewPager, I have an ImageView that displays a semi-transparent picture.

For some reason, when I try my solution on a Galaxy Nexus (4.0.4), it leaves a border on the left and right side of the ViewPager, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of Galaxy Nexus with ViewPager problem]

I've tried this on the following devices and it does **not** give that problem:

- Nexus S (4.1.1)
- Nexus One (2.3.6)
- Evo 4G (CM7.2, 2.3.7)
- Android emulator

Would anyone be able to take a look at the [simplified source code](https://bitbucket.org/gautamjain/transparencytest/src) and help me out (especially if you have a Galaxy Nexus)?  Thanks!

Btw, this is an attempt to solve an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013334/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-demo-screen-for-an-android-app) myself, for which I couldn't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through my code again and tried commenting/uncommenting sections to see if I could get rid of the problem.

I narrowed it down to the custom style I was applying to my activity.  In it, I had the following item:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

Removing this item fixed the issue, although I still don't understand why.  Maybe something related to this question - [How to create a transparent activity WITHOUT windowIsFloating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888263/how-to-create-a-transparent-activity-without-windowisfloating)

I had originally included this item after reading the following question - 
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Anyway, I hope this saves someone else a significant amount of time in debugging.