# SurfaceView inside Dialog (or Activity with Theme.Dialog) has layout glitch

Tags: android, layout, dialog, surfaceview, visual-glitch

I'm trying to show a `SurfaceView` inside an `Activity` that has a theme that extends `Theme.Dialog` (you can think as I'm trying to show it inside a `Dialog` class), but I'm having some layout glitch.

I couldn't make a picture because the glitch vanish when taking a screenshot :/ but anyway what you see is that the "hole" of `SurfaceView` is moved from its original position and it create some weird overlay effect...

The problem seems to be related with the flag `windowIsFloating`, if I set it to false the glitch goes away...

Any idea for a possible workaround to keep using `windowIsFloating` flag?

---

Simple layout to reproduce the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="250dp"
             android:layout_height="250dp"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:padding="30dp"
             android:background="#ff0">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and modify your activity's theme like this to reproduce the issue:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to solve the glitch, simply `windowIsFloating` flag is very buggy with `SurfaceView`...

So, following also the answer here [How to create a transparent activity WITHOUT windowIsFloating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888263/how-to-create-a-transparent-activity-without-windowisfloating), I ended up by creating a theme that extends Dialog's theme but set `windowIsFloating` flag to `false` and `windowIsTranslucent` to `true`.

That way you need manually to create a layout that behave like a Dialog, but you don't have any glitch and your background can be fully transparent :)

---

Symple example of a theme that will do the trick:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Then you need to apply margins to your layout, otherwise it will be fullscreen as a normal Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I share this because it may be useful to others. I've run into a transparency issue with a SurfaceView inside a dialog and the following answer helped me resolve it (and I did not have to use windowIsFloating=false as suggested here although it also does the trick):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061396/875442

As it turned out my problem was both a Z-ordering and a transparency issue.